# Problem using SDCC in a Makefile during the link step

Tags: makefile, undefined-reference, sdcc

The Small Device C Compiler (SDCC) will produce a ihx (Intel Hex) file even if there are undefined reference errors during the link step.  This behavior causes problems when using SDCC in a Makefile because if you set the ihx file to be your make target, then make has no good way of knowing that a previous attempt at linking has failed.

**Is there a way to tell SDCC to suppress the ihx output when there is an undefined reference during linking?  If not, what is the best workaround?** (I already thought of one).

Also, I'm interested in *why* SDCC was designed this way if anyone knows.

**Here's an example of the problem:**

You have a file called test.c which calls an undefined function:

```
void foo();
void main()
{
    foo();
}
```

You have a simple Makefile for building a test.ihx from test.c:

```
test.ihx: test.c
    sdcc test.c
```

You try to compile test.c for the first time and it fails:

```
C:\test>make
sdcc test.c

?ASlink-Warning-Undefined Global '_foo' referenced by module 'test'
make: *** [test.ihx] Error 1
```

You try to fix the problem by changing something that is not a dependency of the ihx (such as the Makefile), and try to compile again:

```
C:\test>make
make: `test.ihx' is up to date.
```

But make doesn't try to compile it because SDCC already created the ihx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about sdcc, so I'm sorry that I can't answer your questions regarding whether the output can be suppressed or why sdcc was designed that way.

I can think of a work-around:  Rename the ihx file after a successful build, and use the new name as the make target.